# Qual é o a Coleção em Scala equivalente a ConcurrentHashMap?

Tags: collection, scala

Olá, como posso implementar um ConcurrentHashMap em Scala?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Além do já constante em java, no pacote [`java.util.concurrent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html), em scala temos uma *extensão* para esta API, também para trabalhar com coleções que são *thread safe*, o pacote [`scala.collection.concurrent`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.concurrent.package). Possui menos classes/interfaces que o java, até por que você pode utilizar as classes da API em java.

Especificamente em relação a [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) do java, que utiliza tabelas hash, lá não temos nada igual, ou seja, que também implemente *map* exclusivamente com [tabelas hash](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabela_de_dispers%C3%A3o).

O que temos lá é a [`TrieMap`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.concurrent.TrieMap) que implementa [`Map`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.concurrent.Map), ela combina na implementação [tabelas hash](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabela_de_dispers%C3%A3o) e [vetor associativo](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vetor_associativo) de [árvores de prefixos](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

Caso não seja o que deseje usar, você pode usar algo assim:

```scala
import scala.collection._
import scala.collection.convert.decorateAsScala._
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap

val cMap: concurrent.Map[String, String] = new ConcurrentHashMap().asScala
```

Desta forma, usa [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) do java em *scala like* =)

P.S.: veja também o [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/67207/qual-%C3%A9-o-a-cole%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-scala-equivalente-a-concurrenthashmap/67224?noredirect=1#comment137362_67224) do [@AnthonyAccioly](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/100/anthony-accioly), bastante interessante o *benchmark* do artigo.

Comment: Excelente resposta. Segue o paper sobre `Tries` com alguns benchmarks interessantes comparando a coleção com `ConcurrentHashMap`, `ConcurrentSkipListMap` e [`NonBlockingHashTable`](http://www.azulsystems.com/blog/cliff/2007-04-23-nonblocking-hashtable-source-code): http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~prokopec/ctries-snapshot.pdf (claro que muito coisa mudou na implementação e na própria JVM, mas é interessante ver em que tipo de carga cada implementação brilha)

Comment: Obrigado aos dois esse paper é excelente!